# Как получить значение AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
function e_arr () {
    $.ajax ({
        /* адрес файла-обработчика запроса */
        url: '/files/sale/ajax_acc.php',
        /* метод отправки данных */
        method: 'POST',
        /* данные, которые мы передаем в файл-обработчик */
        data: {"stat": 'on'}
        /* что нужно сделать до отправки запроса */
    }).done(function (data) {
        /* Преобразуем результат, пришедший от обработчика - преобразуем json-строку обратно в массив */
        var ds = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    });
}
```

Как использовать значение `ds` в другой функции?

Comment: так вы его и получаете, в чем вопрос то?

Comment: Я его получаю но не знаю как получить его для другой функции.
Например function sss () { k = e_arr (); alert (k)}  -- -- Вот как его получить в этом случае????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var result = null;

function e_arr () {
    $.ajax ({
        /* адрес файла-обработчика запроса */
        url: '/files/sale/ajax_acc.php',
        /* метод отправки данных */
        method: 'POST',
        /* данные, которые мы передаем в файл-обработчик */
        data: {"stat": 'on'},
        async: false
        /* что нужно сделать до отправки запрса */
    }).done(function (data) {
        /* Преобразуем результат, пришедший от обработчика - преобразуем json-строку обратно в массив */
        var ds = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        result = ds;
    });
}
e_arr ();
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Спасибо! Теперь работает